# Is it OK for a mobile app description update to ask users to visit the website instead?

Tags: google, web-applications, apple

Say you're migrating from a mobile app to a PWA. Is it a breach of the ToS for the App Store or [Google Play policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/) to update your app description to something like, "We've migrated to a web app, please visit our web site"?

The App Store review guidelines sort of cover that under ["Minimum functionality"](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality) but that seem to refer to *new* apps, not an update to an existing app that has migrated to web app functionality. Google has something about [affiliate websites](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/#!?zippy_activeEl=webviews-affiliate#webviews-affiliate) but that's not the case here, as both the app and the website belong to the same owner.

PS: this question seems to belong here more than on law.SE, but feel free to migrate where it's most on topic.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get an answer from any of our regulars here.   We know more about websites and little about the app store.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: is there a better SE to ask this question on and not get it viciously closed as "off-topic"?

Comment: Its not off-topic because it is about your website.  If it were only about your app, it would be off-topic.   However, because we typically close questions about apps, we don't attract people with knowledge of them or the app store.   I'm not sure there is a better place to ask.  [android.se] exists, but I'm not sure it would be on-topic there.